# Which Npgsql is the best fit for Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, npgsql

In my project I'm using Npgsql 3.2 and Entity Framework 6.0, but there are lots of problems while importing a table and function into the model, it doesn't recognize Inet datatype from Postgres and auto excludes my table, then I have to go through XML version of DBMX and at the still not working, any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always be using the latest version of Npgsql (currently 3.2.3). There are some limitations and known issues with the Npgsql EF6 provider, but these won't be fixed by using an older version of Npgsql.

The Inet datatype cannot be supported in EF6 because of inherent limitations in EF6's type mapping, which is limited to a closed set of "standard" types. Other specific issues you encounter should be posted as distinct, detailed questions - there may be solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the resolution Shay,but if i use Npgsql 3.2.3,with entity framework 5,will this support Inet?its an urgent projectand i badly need help regarding this Npgsql

Comment: No, not at all. "Non-standard" datatypes such as inet are supported in EF Core - if switching to that is an option for you than you should try it out. Be aware that there's no XML modeling whatsoever and several EF6 features are still missing (e.g. lazy loading), but it may be a good idea to check it out. Another option is simply to represent inet as a text column in your database and perform the conversion in C# when saving/loading.